# How exactly do you unlock new artes?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria

Every once in a while, after a battle, one of my characters will learn a new arte. That's great; new stuff is fun.

However, I can't seem to predict when or if this will ever happen. Is there some way to work towards a specific arte or to at least see the requirements for unlocking the next one? I'm not sure if I'm behind the curve on learning new artes. I'm particularly interested in new seraph artes for use during armitization, since I still only have a single one per element.

I have noticed that changing your title says something about what will unlock next, but I haven't been able to correllate that to actual arte learning. I feel like I've gained a lot more title levels than I have learned artes, but maybe I'm just not paying attention.

What exactly dictates when you learn a new arte?

Comment: Your question specifically shows interest in when you learn new armatized seraphic arts. I could add the required Speed, Technique, and Power for these artes to the answer, but I felt it would only add clutter as there is no way to actually see the current value of these attributes. If you would like to know the specifics anyway please let me know and I will edit my answer.

Comment: @AdamP I don't really need to know specific artes; I've actually started getting more armatized seraph spells since I asked the question. Thanks for the answer! I'm glad someone on this site knows this game so well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your characters have three hidden attributes in ToZ; Speed, Technique, and Power. Every time your title levels up it will increase the attributes, and every title increases them in a different way. Every arte has a minimum requirement of these hidden attributes. Once you meet or exceed this requirement the next time your character levels up they will learn the arte.

This is why some titles change which arte you will learn next. They increase your hidden attributes in such a way that you will meet that artes requirements first.

You can check the [wiki](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/ToZ_-_Sorey:_Artes) for the exact amount of Speed, Technique, and Power you need for any given arte.

Artes used while Armatized are learned by the Seraph. So effectively Seraphs have to learn twice the number of artes, but only have access to half of them at any given time. This might be why it seems you do not have many artes yet.